# SCSS .NET MVC USAGE

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, sass

I have a MVC project where I want to create a scss file and write styles of elements here. I created Main.scss file and wrote:

```
$primary-color: #4f637c;
.navbar-static-top {

  background-color: $primary-color;
}
```

In Index.cshtml I referenced the scss file:

```
 <link href="~/Content/Main.scss" rel="stylesheet" />
```

But it doesn't work. I haven't used scss before how can i use it?

Answer (score 1):

For this you need to compile `scss` file to `css` file using sass compilers
http://sass-lang.com/install

**compilers**

- CodeKit (Paid)
- Compass.app (Paid, Open Source)
- Ghostlab (Paid)
- Hammer(Paid)
- Koala (Open Source)
- LiveReload (Paid, Open Source)
- Prepros
  (Paid) Scout (Open Source)

Answer (score 0):

`SCSS` (and `SASS`, `LESS` for that matter) are preprocessor scripting languages, that needs to be compiled, to create the `CSS` files, that you use as your `CSS` file(s).

If you're using Visual Studio, Mads Kristensen made a really good plugin called ["Web Compiler"](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MadsKristensen.WebCompiler).

It that compiles the files for you, so that any change in the `SCSS` file, is automatically compiled into the `CSS` file.

After compiling your `.scss` file, you will need to point to your `.css` file:

```
<link href="~/Content/Main.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```